# Error en AppStorage (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, xcode

estoy intentado que una variable aumente su valor al presionar un botón y si ese valor es mayor a 2 se le sume +1 a otra variable, yo lo hice con un if que y al momento de escribir que la variable 2 sume su valor me dice: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' struct

```
@AppStorage ("num1") var num1: Int = 0
@AppStorage ("num2") var num2: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Button(action: {
            num1 += 1
        }) {
            Image("+1")
                .resizable()
        }
            if num1 > 2
            {
                num2 += 1
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La validación debe ir dentro del `action` del botón:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage ("num1") var num1: Int = 0
    @AppStorage ("num2") var num2: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                num1 += 1
                if num1 > 2 {
                    num2 += 1
                }
                print("Num 1: \(num1)")
                print("Num 2: \(num2)")
            }){
            Image("1").resizable()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El código imprimiría:

```
Num 1: 1
Num 2: 0
Num 1: 2
Num 2: 0
Num 1: 3
Num 2: 1
Num 1: 4
Num 2: 2
Num 1: 5
Num 2: 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!